# Passing appImage key to electron-builder in Cordova

Tags: cordova

I'm using Cordova including a Linux appImage target.  I have set build.json to

```
{
  "electron": {
      "linux": {
      "package": [ "AppImage" ]
      },
      "windows": {
      "package": [ "portable" ]
      }
  }
}
```

However I can't find a way to configure my Cordova project with the equivalent of

```
{
  "appImage": {
    "systemIntegration": "doNotAsk"
  }
}
```

Where can I put (something like) that so that Cordova's electron-builder puts it into platforms/electron/build/builder-effective-config.yaml?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`cordova-electron@1.1.0` has just been released and introduced the ability to append package top-level key options.

Here is the PR that introduced and explains how to set the options: https://github.com/apache/cordova-electron/pull/51

For a quick snippet, the configurations would look something like this:

```
{
  "electron": {
    "linux": {
      "package": [
        "tar.bz2",
        { 
          "appImage": {
            "systemIntegration": "doNotAsk"
          }
        }
      ],
      "arch": ["x64"]
    }
  }
}
```

In this example it will create a `tar.bz2` and `appImage`. The appImage will have the `systemIntegration` setting applied.